# How to draw "rays" in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

How do I draw "Rays" emitting from an object in an image in Photoshop?

[image]

Example from [http://www.pxleyes.com](http://www.pxleyes.com/ext-tutorial/photoshop/3085/Burst-of-Rays.html)

Comment: drawing the shape of one ray and giving it a gradient should works.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Quick & dirty method

Use readily available `custom shape`, which has been included in the installation since probably CS 1 — maybe even before that. I didn't realize its powers at first, mainly because the small thumbnail is distorted with a heavy moiré pattern (here highlighted):

[image: "ray" shape]

Just draw that shape behind the object you want to "emit rays". Here are the shape's `path` highlighted so you could have a better look how does it really look like; and the final result of the mockup.

[image: pentagon emitting rays] [image]

The `custom shape` has many limitations, sure, but it is the quickest method with a vanilla installation of Photoshop.

---

### More unique method

Pick up the `pen` tool and draw a `shape` like:

[image: a ray]

This would be one of your rays. Copy it, modify them if you wish and rotate them, so they all are pointing into one spot. While this isn't too hard, it takes considerably more time than the first method, especially if you are approaching the deadline.

---

The fading of the rays could be achieved with a `layer mask`, which you could e.g. `fill` with a `radial gradient`.

Comment: If you're going to go the ray-by-ray approach, it helps if you start with a vertical or horizontal ray (so you can get the proportions and angles right), do one transform, then use `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+T` to automatically duplicate the layer and replay the transform. It should only take you a minute or two to get all of the rays.

Answer (score 16):

Here's my way...

[image: photo1]

Prepare an empty layer. Draw a rectangular marquee across the half of the layer. (like on the image above).

[image]

Fill that selection with your desired ray color.

[image]

Select Filter > Distort > Wave. Select the Square type and adjust the wavelength to increase/decrease bars (max and min the same value). Apply.

[image]

Select Filter > Distort > Polar Coordinates. Select 'Rectangular to Polar'.

[image]

Modify your generated rays. You're done. =]

Answer (score 3):

There are many [ways](http://teqnoqolor.com/articles/sunbursts-in-photoshop-the-right-way/) to draw sunbursts in Photoshop and Illustrator. But [this](http://www.slicktutorials.com/vector_sunburst) is by far the slickest.

Comment: Please don't simply link to another website; actually answer the question and include the link to support the answer.

Comment: I did answer the question. If you actually view the links, you'd see that it'd be impractical (also pointless) for me to duplicate their content in this answer. This is a Q&A site, not a site for aggregating tutorials.

Comment: Your first link is dead. Good thing you didn't pointlessly duplicate the technique here.

Comment: it's 2022,  both your links are useless now.